# Creating simple calculator with bison & flex in C++ (not C)

Tags: c++, bison, abstract-syntax-tree, flex-lexer

I would like to create simple C++ calculator using bison and flex. Please note I'm new to the creating parsers. I already found few examples in bison/flex but they were all written in C.

My goal is to create C++ code, where classes would contain nodes of values, operations, funcs - to create AST (evaluation would be done just after creating whole AST - starting from the root and going forward).

For example:

```
my_var = sqrt(9 ** 2 - 32) + 4 - 20 / 5
my_var * 3
```

Would be parsed as:

```
        =
      /   \
my_var     +
         /   \
     sqrt     -
       |     / \
       -    4   /
      / \      / \
    **   32   20  5
   /  \
  9    2
```

and the second AST would look like:

```
       *
      / \
my_var   3
```

Then following pseudocode reflects AST:

```
ast_root = create_node('=', new_variable("my_var"), exp)
```

where *exp* is:

```
exp = create_node(OPERATOR, val1, val2)
```

but NOT like this:

```
$$ = $1 OPERATOR $3
```

because this way I directly get value of operation instead of creation the Node.

I believe the Node should contain type (of operation), val1 (Node), val2 (Node). In some cases val2 would be NULL, like above mentioned *sqrt* which takes in the end one argument. Right?

It will be nice if you can propose me C++ skeleton (without evaluation) for above described problem (including *.y file creating AST) to help me understand the way of creating/holding Nodes in AST. Code can be snipped, just to let me get the idea.

I'll also be grateful if you point me to an existing (possibly simple) example if you know any.

Thank you all for your time and assistance!

Comment: I heard bison support for C++ is BAD. I just have my functions as a wrapper to my C++ code. It works well. Half the time i just write the data in C since most of it is datastructs being filled out and does not need STD objs or classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.progtools.org/compilers/tutorials/cxx_and_bison/cxx_and_bison.html is a mini-tutorial which should create something like what you want.

Comment: That mini-tutorial looks like good place to start. I hope I will be able to implement whole calculator in the way I described above. Thank you for the link.